# Hibernate "String or binary data would be truncated" exception on JBPM process variable

Tags: hibernate, jbpm

My JBPM 7.44/Redhat PAM 7.10 case application has a process which nests stages and our stages nest tasks that map to JBPM tasks; the application loops through stages that loop through tasks that refer to JBPM tasks.

I moved some of the processing from the main process to an embedded subprocess.  When the application goes from the first to the second stage I now get

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602)
```

as the end of the stack trace.  This occurs in the script

```
System.out.println("Task setup for stage enter");
com.me.MyStage stage = (com.me.MyStage ) kcontext.getVariable("caseFile_Stage");
System.out.println("Starting stage {name=" + stage.getName() + "}");
// Tasks
java.util.List<com.me.MyTask> tasks = stage.getTasks();
System.out.println("1 - # tasks=" + tasks.size());
kcontext.setVariable("Tasks", tasks);   // error occurs here
```

The Hibernate tags on the tasks field are:

```
@javax.persistence.OneToMany(cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
@javax.persistence.JoinTable(name = "STAGE_TASKS_JOIN")
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("tasks") @org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private java.util.List<com.me.MyTask> tasks;
```

Perhaps I misunderstand the error, but it seems like the data in the records could not be truncated by the assignment - what is really going on and how do I need to change the tags to avoid the the exception?  I think the issue is that it is trying to persist the data from the tasks in stage 1 when I make this assignment to use the tasks in stage 2 - but assigning to the process variable using kcontext also seems it should not force any persistence except perhaps to JBPM's VariableInstanceLog (which I see warnings about in other environments, not errors). VariableInstanceLog is defined as a varchar(255) for the field "oldValue" and as a "text" for the value field.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the VariableInstanceLog length setting up a different value to this system property

```
org.jbpm.var.log.length
```

modifying accordingly that column in your database.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps I should have added more.  I had that property set and what was actually going wrong is there is another field for the previous value of the variable in that table.  I field for the current value was set to type "text" so I changed the definition of the field for the old value of the variable to "text" too

Answer (score 1):

Part of the solution, which I suspected, is that inserting into VariableInstanceLog is throwing the exception.  If this were a less sensitive system I could drop/add the table.  It may be that at one point I used a JBoss property to refer to the tables as varchar(4000) when they are in reality only varchar(255).

```
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'insert into VariableInstanceLog (log_date, externalId, oldValue, processId, processInstanceId, value, variableId, variableInstanceId) values (@P0, @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7) select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS GENERATED_KEYS',N'@P0 datetime2,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 bigint,@P5 nvarchar(4000),@P6 nvarchar(4000),@P7 nvarchar(4000)','2021-10-08 15:57:47.2710000',N'ams-pam_2.0.3-m1',N'[MyTask(id=172488, owner=0BD0194B-0000-4AED-9161-43D030686D7E, name=Stage1Task1P, dateCompleted=null, dateCreated=2021-10-08T14:55:55.625, status=STARTED, MyTask(id=172489, owner=0BD0194B-0000-4AED-9161-43D030686D7E, name=Stage1Task1P, dateCompleted=null, dateCreated=2021-10-08T14:56:23.813, status=STARTED]',N'AMS_Workflow',7184,N'[MyTask(id=172490, owner=0BD0194B-0000-4AED-9161-43D030686D7E, name=Stage2Task1P, dateCompleted=null, dateCreated=null, status=null]',N'Tasks',N'Tasks'    0   99  12  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Put property in your standalone.xml config file

```
<system-properties>


        <property name="org.jbpm.var.log.length" value="20000"/>


    </system-properties>
```

or find out more here:
https://dzone.com/articles/increase-the-default-process-variable-size-in-jbpm